# Why i can't increment in mongoose / mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to increment but the result always shows that it is undefined.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TestSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    total: Number


});

var Test = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema);

var arr = [2,4,5,6,7,8];
var test = new Test();

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    test.total += item;
});

console.log(test.total);
```

`console.log(test.total)` will printout undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because "total" is not defined to start with. So instead define something:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var testSchema = new Schema({
  total: Number
});

var Test = mongoose.model( 'Test', testSchema );

var arr = [2,4,5,6,7,8];

var test = new Test({ "total": 0 });

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
  test.total += item;
});

console.log(test);
```

Outputs:

```
2
4
5
6
7
8
{ _id: 5641850e7a8c9b001842c6d2, total: 32 }
```

Just like it should.

Alternately, at least supply a schema default.

```
var testSchema = new Schema({
  total: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

But if nothing is there, then the value is `undefined` and trying to increment an undefined value just returns nothing in result.

Comment: Oh my, I almost forgot that I have to define it, even though it is a number type. Other programming language like Java if I'm not mistaken, defined the number's field to zero by default.